# SQL 2 INNER JOIN with group by

Tags: mysql, join

I have SQL like below:

```
SELECT 
      p1.*
FROM 
      payment p1
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT 
            p2.contract_id_fk, 
            MAX(p2.payment_id_pk) AS maxpay
      FROM 
            payment p2 
       GROUP BY  
            p2.contract_id_fk) p2
ON (
      p1.payment_id_pk = p2.maxpay)
LEFT JOIN 
      contracts c
ON (
      c.contract_id_pk = p1.contract_id_fk)
WHERE 
       p1.contract_id_fk != 0 
AND 
       p1.payment_remain=0;
```

The first join is to get the last record when I use `group by` 
my problem is in the second join. It doesn't get the data from the second table named `contracts`.
The result is the right record that I need but without the data from the second joined table.

Comment: can you describe this question more details ?

Answer (score 1):

You've only asked for the first table. `SELECT p1.*`  You need to include whatever fields you need from the second table in the select, ie `select p1.*, p2.*`